# Calc 2 Limit Comparison Test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to find out if it converges.
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sqrt{k}}{(k^3+1)}$$
The solutions manual says to use $k^{-5/2}$ as a model case to use for the limit comparison test.
I'm not sure how one would be able to come up with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{k}}{k^3+1}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{k}}{k^3+1}$$
First note that
$$\left|\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k^3+1}\right|\leq\left|\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k^3}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{k^{\frac52}}\right|$$
Also since $\frac52\gt 1$, we have
$$\zeta\left(\frac52\right)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{1}{k^{\frac52}}\right|=\mbox{convergent}$$
Now lets use the limit comparison test
$$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{\left|\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k^3+1}\right|}{\left|\frac{1}{k^{\frac52}}\right|}=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{k^3}{k^3+1}\right|$$
$$=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{k^3}}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{1+0}\right|=1$$
Therefore by the limit comparison test,
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k^3+1}\right|=\mbox{convergent}$$
Which implies that
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{k}}{k^3+1}=\mbox{absolutely convergent}$$

Answer (score 0):

As $k \to \infty$, top looks like $k^{1/2}$ and bottom looks like $k^3$, so their ratio is $1/k^{5/2}$.

Comment: Maybe you want a third "looks like" at the end.

Comment: @zhw. what do you mean? to day "their ratio looks like" just for the symmetry of expression?

Comment: because it's not true that the ratio equals that

Comment: @zhw. $$\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k^3+1} \approx \frac{k^{1/2}}{k^3} = \frac{1}{k^{5/2}}$$

Comment: So the ratio is *like* $1/k^{5/2},$ but to say it *is* $1/k^{5/2}$ is incorrect.

Comment: @zhw the word *ratio* in that expression refers **not** to the original ratio, but to the ratio of the approximated quantities, which *is* **exactly** $1/k^{5/2}$

Comment: OK, then it's a grammar mistake. I stick by my first comment. Anyway it would have been easier just to say the $k$th term is $<1/k^{5/2}.$

Comment: @zhw.OP needed a push for *limit comparison test*, not sure it is a mistake :-) but thanks for commenting

Comment: Yes you're right about the limit comparison test; lost track of the original question. So we're all good. Time for lunch.